# how to type "\ as a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, windows, path

I writing a python program for Windows. The path consists of the foldername + filename, where the filename changes in each iteration. 
The folder address is always the same so I write the code as:

```
 path =  "%s%s" % ("C:\Users\ME\raw_image\", filename)
```

However I have noticed that the character \" is considered as escape and also \r is problematic. I tried a couple of things but could not figure out how to get rid of this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Rakesh, Python's 'raw' strings do not support an odd number of trailing backslashes. Use `os.path.join(r"C:\Users\ME\raw_image", filename)`.

Comment: '\' is the escape character in python strings. To print the escape character itself as a string, you can escape it! `\\` is what you are after.

Comment: When working with paths, it's is better to use `os.path.join(...) ` instead

Comment: @JeffreyDevloo I normally do,  for now I am creating some xml file to feed in a program which works only in windows... long story short, I had to do it this way, otherwise I always use os.path.jon(...)

Comment: @Rakesh, please remove your comment with an invalid raw string that ends with a backslash. It's attracting naive upvotes, which is misleading and a waste of everyone's time that tries it only to get a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options.  Either use a raw string for the folder path:

```
path =  r"%s\%s" % (r"C:\Users\ME\raw_image", filename)
```

or escape the backslashes using a backslash:

```
path =  "%s%s" % ("C:\\Users\\ME\\raw_image\\", filename)
```

---

As noted by @Erik-Sun, using raw strings requires special handling of the a trailing backslash, i.e. trying `r"C:\Users\ME\raw_image\"` will cause a syntax error because Python will interpret the trailing backslash as an escape on the double-quote.

To get around this I simply moved the last backslash to the unformated string `r'%\%'`.

Comment: Thanks, I am so used to using pathlib, I just don't think about backslashes much anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\\` instead of `\` in your code, like this example:

```
>>> print("C:\\Users\\Me\\raw_image\\")
C:\Users\Me\raw_image\
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add another backslash like this:

```
path =  "%s%s" % ("C:\\Users\\ME\\raw_image\\", filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather suggest you to use the str.format() function, because this avoids you to 'escape' the backslash.

e.g.

```
>>> filename = "filename.txt"
>>> path = "C:\\Users\\Me\\raw_image\\{}".format(filename)
>>> print(path)
```

output will be:

```
C:\\Users\\Me\\raw_image\\filename.txt
```